# Função de contagem Regressiva?

Tags: javascript, contador, setinterval

Estou tendo uns problemas no meu projeto. Pretendo fazer um contador regressivo de 10 a 0 que é ativado por um botão "Iniciar", o problema é que estou tendo dificuldade em desenvolver um código de contagem regressiva. Queria sugestões de conceitos ou comandos que posso acrescentar no meu código.:)

```
//Criar uma variável para o display do contador
let Contador = document.getElementById("TeladoContador").style.display;
//Criar uma variável para o botão do contador
let Iniciar = document.getElementById("btn");
//Criar um evento para o botão com onclick
Iniciar.addEventListener("click",exibir());
//Criar uma função para exibir o display do contador
Contador.textContent = exibir(Number);
//Criar uma função para realizar a contagem
setInterval(function exibir(Number){
   Number = Number < 10 ? Number : Number;
   Contador.textContent = Number;
    
}, 1000)
//Exibir a contagem no display
```

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer a contagem regressiva, você precisa saber quando o tempo acaba.

Supondo que você queira um timer de 10 segundos, você precisa verificar constantemente se a hora atual é anterior ao tempo de expiração e quantos segundos ainda faltam para acabar.

Abaixo, coloquei um exemplo simples que faz basicamente isso.
Nos comentários do código você consegue verificar como essa lógica se aplica.

**Lembre-se**: você várias validações devem ser feitas para garantir o funcionamento correto. Portanto o código abaixo é só uma ideia de uma estratégia para isso. Por exemplo, ele **não** verifica se foi ou não preenchido um valor em segundos para contar

```js
//elementos da paǵina para serem manipulados no JS
const btIniciar = document.getElementById("iniciar")
const btParar = document.getElementById("parar")
const inputSegundos = document.getElementById("segundos")
const mostrador = document.getElementById("mostrador")
//a variável segundos irá ser utilizada para calcular o tempo de expiração do timer
let segundos;
//a variável interval Id será usada para parar a contagem
let intervalId;

//na função iniciar, é calculado a hora de expiração, bem como dado início ao setInterval
function iniciar() {
  //quantos segundos o usuário indicou?
  segundos = +inputSegundos.value;
  //quando começou a contagem? Essa informação é necessária para poder calcular o momento de expiração
  // new Date() significa 'agora' e getTime() retorna os milissegundos referente a data
  const horaInicio = new Date().getTime();
  //com os milissegundos de agora é fácil calcular os milissegundos da hora de expiração
  const horaExpirar = new Date(horaInicio + (segundos * 1000))
  // com essas duas informações, é possível iniciar a contagem
  intervalId = window.setInterval(function() {
    //para cada execução deste intervalo
    //verifica-se a hora exata da execução
    let agora = new Date();
    milisegundosParaExpirar = horaExpirar.getTime() - agora.getTime();
    //e verifica-se quantos segundos faltam
    segundosExpirar = Math.floor(milisegundosParaExpirar / 1000)
    if (segundosExpirar > 0) {
      //se faltam mais do que zero, o timer ainda não expirou
      mostrador.innerHTML = segundosExpirar;
    } else {
      mostrador.innerHTML = "Tempo esgotado!";
    }
  }, 500)
}

function parar() {
  window.clearInterval(intervalId)
}

btIniciar.addEventListener('click', iniciar)
btParar.addEventListener('click', parar)
```

```css
#mostrador{
  widht: 100px;
  heigth: 100px;
  font-size: 18pt;
}
```

```html
<label for="segundos">
  <input type="number" id="segundos" min="1" max="59" step="1" />
<label>

<button id="iniciar" title="Iniciar contagem regressiva">▶️</button>
<button id="parar" title="Parar contagem">⏹️</button>

<div id="mostrador"></div>
```